# Android: DownloadManager - Notification Sticking

Tags: android, android-download-manager

I'm downloading an image from my server using the `Download Manager`.

It downloads the file fine and puts it where I want it to. But for some reason the **notification sticks and I can't seem to remove** it. The code for the download manager is as follows:

```
mDownloadManager = (DownloadManager) getSystemService(Context.DOWNLOAD_SERVICE);
registerReceiver(onComplete, new IntentFilter(DownloadManager.ACTION_DOWNLOAD_COMPLETE));

Uri uri = Uri.parse("URL"));

long enqueue = mDownloadManager.enqueue(new DownloadManager.Request(uri)
            .setAllowedNetworkTypes(DownloadManager.Request.NETWORK_WIFI)
            .setAllowedOverRoaming(false)
            .setTitle("Title")
            .setDescription("File description")
            .setDestinationInExternalPublicDir("Folder", "Filename")
            .setNotificationVisibility(DownloadManager.Request.VISIBILITY_VISIBLE));

BroadcastReceiver onComplete = new BroadcastReceiver() {
    public void onReceive(Context ctxt, Intent intent) {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Download Completed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
 };
```

**How do I remove the notification once it has been downloaded?**.

I have tried setting all the different notification visibility modes with no luck. Is there something I can do from the BroadcastReceiver once it is finished?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I managed to work out my problem. In the `BroadcastReceiver` I had to get the download id from the intent and remove that from the `DownloadManager`.

```
BroadcastReceiver onComplete = new BroadcastReceiver() {
    public void onReceive(Context ctxt, Intent intent) {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Download Completed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        // Get the download_id of the completed download.
        long download_id = intent.getLongExtra(DownloadManager.EXTRA_DOWNLOAD_ID, -1);

        // Remove the completed download from the DownloadManager
        mDownloadManager.remove(download_id);
    }
 };
```

I also want to note that by doing `mDownloadManager.remove(download_id)`, this will delete the file from memory. I had to add additional code to save the file permanently in the location I wanted it to save originally.

Comment: Please use DownloadManager.EXTRA_DOWNLOAD_ID instead of hardcoding "extra_download_id"

Comment: No other solution ? I mean that it's not very clean to clear the notification by removing the downloaded file (and you have to first save it) : file copy and file deletion for just a notification clear !